# Search Bar in iOS App to search PHP/MYSQLi and parse JSON back to iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, xcode, mysqli

I want to thank everyone here from the past and in the future who have helped me on my journey.  So, I have a new app for iOS where I want to search a MYSQLi database from the iOS app.  From there, I want it to populate the results in a UITableView.  I already have the code for the Table View.  I also already know how to use the json_encode function in PHP.  My question is how do you send a query to a MYSQL database from an iOS app and have it come back as JSON?  For example, below is how I search my MYSQL database from my website.  I want to do the same thing from inside my iOS app.

I should mention, I am already using JSONSerialization class and the parsing is good.  I just don't know how to send queries from iOS to MYSQL and get something back.

```
<?php

        $search = $_POST['searchquery'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM blacklisted WHERE MATCH (name, address, city, state, zip) AGAINST ('%$search%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($search == null)
        {
            echo "Search The Blacklist Today!";
        }
        else if($search != null)
        {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $zip = $row['zip'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $persons = $row['persons'];
        $damages = $row['damages'];
        $complaint = $row['complaint'];
    ?>
```

[The Blacklist JSON Output](http://www.zebradatasolutions.com/theblacklist/json.php)

[The Blacklist](http://www.zebradatasolutions.com/theblacklist/main.php)

```
#import "Search.h"

@implementation Search

NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSArray *complaints;
NSString * json;
NSData * data;
NSMutableString* mainlabel;
NSMutableString* detaillabel;
NSMutableURLRequest *request;

@synthesize searchfield, table;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

{
    NSString*searchtext = searchfield.text;

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", searchtext];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.zebradatasolutions.com/theblacklist/jsonsearch.php"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion: YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue: postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: & response error: & error];

    json =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    data =[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: nil];

    complaints = [dictionary valueForKey:@"blacklistsearch"];

    [table reloadData];

    NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary);

}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (cell == nil)

    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSString * name = complaints[indexPath.row][@"name"];

    NSString *address = complaints[indexPath.row][@"address"];

    NSString *city = complaints[indexPath.row][@"city"];

    NSString *state = complaints[indexPath.row][@"state"];

    NSString *zip = complaints[indexPath.row][@"zip"];

    NSString *date = complaints[indexPath.row][@"date"];

    NSString *persons = complaints[indexPath.row][@"persons"];

    NSString *damages = complaints[indexPath.row][@"damages"];

    NSString *complaint = complaints[indexPath.row][@"complaint"];

    mainlabel = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    detaillabel = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [mainlabel appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];

    [detaillabel appendString: [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@\n%@, %@\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@\n", address, city, state, zip, date, persons, damages, complaint]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    cell.textLabel.text = mainlabel;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = detaillabel;

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor magentaColor];

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;


}

-(IBAction) closekeyboard: (id)sender
{
    [searchfield resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrong to set the search parameter in post data.

instead of

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", searchtext];
```

you should do something like

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myValue=%@&otherValue=%@", searchtext,otherTextYouWant];
```

where "myValue" and "otherValue" are the keys you'll use server side to retrieve the value searchtext and otherTextYouWant
( like `$_POST['myValue']` )

Moreover, you should encode all your param before send to post, maybe using this

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeStrirng:(NSString*)baseString UsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {        
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,  (CFStringRef)baseString,NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
}
```

so your row code will became

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myValue=%@", [self urlEncodeString:searchtext ] searchtext UsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Remeber to escape received searchtext server side before query it to db, using addSlashes ( or changed way to query db, maybe using PDO ) to avoid sql-injection

I hope it could help you

Comment: Thanks Luca… This is the right answer but i'm still a bit confused.  So MYSQL is listening for a $_POST['searchtext'] and i'm trying to deliver it from iOS.  My search engine works in a browser as you can see… So if there are many users using this app, will I be creating problems without using sessions on the php side?

Comment: So, the server retrive all params request ( so POST and GET, that are retrievable with $_POST['param_key'] or $_GET['param_key'], USING PHP ) while MySql is the DB you use to store and retrieve all your informations. Once you have the client params ( in my example is the value associated at 'myValue' key ) you build the string query then call the PHP method 'mysqli_query' that return the query result (sucha as array or object structure), if no error occours.
About session use, i suggest you to avoid it if you need to perform a simple search query on server db. Anyway there aren't problem